# Docker unexpected behavior when using dockerfile to yum install a package inside container

Tags: docker, centos

Hi to make my question clear, I will use sever pictures here.
First, I want to install rstudio server in my new docker image, the rpm file I downloaded beforehand,using

```
wget https://download2.rstudio.org/server/centos6/x86_64/rstudio-server-rhel-1.3.959-x86_64.rpm
```

here is my Dockerfile:

[image]

With Dockerfile and rserver rpm in current folder I want to build the image using :

```
docker build -t temp:temp .
```

However,sometimes the setup process is terminated due to unable to connect to the mirror site at the step `yum install`, sometimes it succeeded with some sites weird:

[image]

This success process mentions a mirror site:mirrors.163.com, however I never set mirror site as this, actually I didn't even know this site.

I checked my settings in three places:
1 my host machine's /etc/yum.repos.d/CentOS-Base.repo:
[image]

2 The container run according to that build up image's /etc/yum.repos.d/CentOS-Base.repo:

[image]

3 I also checked my docker's /etc/docker/daemon.json:

[image]

So here is my question:
1 why the build image process sometimes failed and sometimes succeed?
2 why the building process used a mirror site I have never seen and never set before? Or it was set to some place I haven't been awared of?

Another background info is that since the host machine is in china,due to policy it can't freely access the website outside freely, that's why the mirror setting is so critical, sometimes it takes us several hours to figure out the correct mirror site setting.

3 So the last question is, is there a way to quickly setup the mirror set inside a country in order for the docker to run installation freely?

My host machine and docker image are all centos 7.4

Comment: For future reference, please always include the actual code in your question rather than images of the code.

Comment: @datawookie I want to do that ,but actually, all the code is on the server and the code is actually can't get copy/paste, I think it is very hard for us to debug but that is our company's policy. So here I use the snapshot to tell others what happened.

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)  None of the PNG files you've included can be used to reproduce your issue (neither Docker nor yum will accept image files as input) and the output image isn't readable, nor can someone copy the error message out of the output to search for it in other places.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to lock down the mirror being used to download packages then you need to modify `/etc/yum.repos.d/CentOS-Base.repo` on the image.

Create a local `CentOS-Base.repo` that specifies a working mirror. For example, http://mirror.centos.org/ (but you need to choose one that works reliably for you).

`CentOS-Base.repo`

```
[base]
name=CentOS-$releasever - Base
baseurl=http://mirror.centos.org/centos/$releasever/os/$basearch/
gpgcheck=1
gpgkey=file:///etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-CentOS-7

[updates]
name=CentOS-$releasever - Updates
baseurl=http://mirror.centos.org/centos/$releasever/updates/$basearch/
gpgcheck=1
gpgkey=file:///etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-CentOS-7

[extras]
name=CentOS-$releasever - Extras
baseurl=http://mirror.centos.org/centos/$releasever/extras/$basearch/
gpgcheck=1
gpgkey=file:///etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-CentOS-7

[centosplus]
name=CentOS-$releasever - Plus
baseurl=http://mirror.centos.org/centos/$releasever/centosplus/$basearch/
gpgcheck=1
enabled=0
gpgkey=file:///etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-CentOS-7
```

`Dockerfile`

```
FROM rstudio/r-base:devel-centos7 AS base

WORKDIR /R_setup

COPY CentOS-Base.repo /etc/yum.repos.d/CentOS-Base.repo

RUN wget -q https://download2.rstudio.org/server/centos7/x86_64/rstudio-server-rhel-2023.12.1-402-x86_64.rpm

RUN sed -i 's/enabled=1/enabled=0/' /etc/yum/pluginconf.d/fastestmirror.conf && \
    yum clean all && \
    yum makecache fast && \
    yum update && \
    yum install -y rstudio-server-rhel-2023.12.1-402-x86_64.rpm

CMD ["bash"]
```

In the `Dockerfile` you copy that configuration across into the correct location and it will then be used by subsequent `yum` commands. You also explicitly disabled the `fastestmirror` plugin.

FYI I have replaced the `.rpm` file that you are using by one that's directly downloaded during the Docker build. However, you can replace this with your original approach where you `COPY` across an `.rpm`. Personally I prefer to have the whole thing wrapped up in the `Dockerfile`.

Comment: It seems I shouldn't touch our server's yum mirror setup, but I can do whatever I want for  the image/container, so If what really matters is the setup inside image, I guess I should create a file named "my_yum_setting_for_image" and then use COPY my_yum_setting_for_image /etc/yum.repos.d/CentOS-Base.repo to finish it, thank you for your answer.

Comment: By the way, do you know how come "mirror.163.com" shows up? Is that due to fastestmirror plugin you mensioned to get the fatest mirror itself?

Comment: My suggestion won't involve any changes to your server. Create the `CentOS-Base.repo` file in the same folder as `Dockerfile`.

And, yes, it's selecting that mirror using the plugin which polls a list of mirrors to find the best one AFAIK.